# iOS App Store - Can you transfer app when it's "Waiting for Review"

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, app-transfer

I'm interested in transferring an iOS Application I developed, to a different iTunes Connect account.  I'm wondering if this transfer process can be done, while the app is in a "Waiting for Review" state.  According to [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html) the supported app states are:

- Ready for Sale
- Prepare for Submission
- Developer Removed From Sale
- Invalid Binary
- Developer Rejected
- Rejected

It would seem then that the answer to my question is no.  However, Apple's wording doesn't exclude other types.

> "The app status can be one of the following, assuming that there is at least one approved version of the app:"

For instance, had their documentation read as follows, it would have been more clear:

> "The app status MUST be one of the following, assuming that there is at
>   least one approved version of the app.  With any other app state, transfers are not supported:"

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:  No, you cannot transfer your app while it is in "Waiting for Review" status.

You can verify this if you have an app currently in "Waiting for Review" status.  Log into your iTunes Connect account, and navigate to the "App Information" tab.

You should see an "Additional Information" section on the page, which should contain a link titled "Transfer App".  If your app is in "Waiting for Review", that link will not be present.